# constructor error for array of structure, error msg: no instance of constructor matches the argument list

Tags: c++, constructor, compiler-errors

```
Person* studentList[5];
studentList[0] = new Student("Jane", 1);
studentList[1] = new Student("Jim", 2);
studentList[2] = new Student("Jacques", 3);
studentList[3] = new Student("Juan", 4);
studentList[4] = new Student("Junlian", 5);
```

Student is a child structure of Person, the last 5 lines showing the error no instance of constructor Student::Student matches the argument list, I can't figure the problem.
Here is the constructor:

```
Student::Student(char * na, int nm) {
this->name = na;
this->number = nm;
}
```

I would appreciate it if anyone can help explain.

Comment: A warning about string pointers to character arrays: It makes it very easy to have a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) if you store an Automatic (AKA local) variable by mistake. Oce the Automatic ariable reaches the end of its scope it will no longer be safe to access. Worse, this typically will not generate a visible  error immediately, leaving you scratching your head, looking for a bug in the wrong spot later.

Answer (score 2):

String literals in C++ (unlike in C) are `const char*`. They cannot be converted to non-const `char*`. To compile your program you need to change your constructor signature to

```
Student::Student(const char* na, int nm)
```

You also need to make sure `name` is declared as `const char*` in `Student`.